# Facebook edge.create

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have added the edge.create event and the event can be fired by the browser as well. But how can I check if the user has liked the page when they come back to the site?

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.init({appId: 'YOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_ID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
 FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
 // OK
 });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You are going to want to take a look at the [signed_request documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/)...
This signed request is facebooks method of validating that the user that made the request is indeed "who he/she says they are".  It is encrypted and and uses your application secret to decode the values.
 Once you parse this signed request you will have the data you need.

```
function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
  list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 
  // decode the data
  $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
  $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

  if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
    error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
    return null;
  }

  // check sig
  $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
  if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
    error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
    return null;
  }

  return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
  return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}
```

Comment: Signed requests are only available for page tabs running in facebook, not stand-alone sites (afaik)

Answer (score 1):

If your question is about `like` for `URL` that you can get this information only for user who authorized your application and granted `user_likes` permission. To do so issue next FQL query:

```
SELECT user_id, url FROM url_like WHERE user_id = me() and url="URL_OF_PAGE"
```

If your page have an ID in OpenGraph (or you speak about Facebook Page), by querying Graph API for [`user`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)'s [`likes`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#likes) connection:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes/OPEN_GRAPH_OBJECT_ID
```

But if you speaking about Facebook Page and Application running in Page Tab, you don't need anything special to get this information since it will be passed within `signed_request` (sample php code using PHP-SDK):

```
$signedRequest = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
$data = $signedRequest['data'];
if ($data['page']['liked']){
  // User is liked this Facebook Page
} else {
  // User is not yet liked Facebook Page
}
```